Will my stuff be "leaded" when soldering?
I've been soldering for some time now. I use 60/40 leaded solder. I usually wash my hands after soldering, but while soldering, I often touch other things, for example: phone, pendrives, keyboard and mouse. I'm wondering if I should clean those stuff, because I never wash my hands after touching them, only after soldering, and I usually eat after that. Or is it a very small amount of lead, or no lead at all, and i shouldn't be worried? I often at at the soldering area too without cleaning it. And if I touch my clothing, for example: shirt while soldering, will there be lead on that?

Metallic lead is mostly harmless (do note that "mostly", though); it's lead compounds that start to get concerning. You should be more concerned about the flux fumes than the lead, I suspect, especially if this is hobbyist-level work.

Does this answer your question? How much lead is really on my hands when soldering?

Are solder fumes bad for me?

Skin contact is irrelevant for the toxicity of lead. That is because the lump metal itself doesn't have enough surface area to reach a toxic exposition dose.
What you have to avoid is inhaling lead fumes and swallowing lead dust. As the high surface area of those creates a lot of lead ions, and those are pretty nasty. So if you are concerned, use a fume extractor. The lead dust is only a problem with playgrounds filled with contaminated sand.

Thank you! I use a 12v pc fan. Is that ok? So if I take care of the fumes, I shouldn't have to worry about my stuff getting lead on them, right? But if I never wash my hands, will that small amount grow big enough to cause problems? What if solder directly touches my stuff? My desk has a mat, that has some burns in it. In those holes I can see some solder. Should I clean that? I'm sorry, if I said anything stupid, or I'm being paranoid, but I'm pretty worried about this.

Also, IINM, there shouldn't be any lead fumes when soldering, since you don't get anywhere near its boiling point and doesn't evaporate. The reason you need a fume extractor is not for the lead.

What is "lead fumes", more exactly? Vaporized flux does not contain lead, afaik. It's still harmful though, but not because of lead.

@BenedekHirth For hobbyist purposes a fan is better than nothing. It really depends on how long you solder, do you sit there for hours assembling a PCBA or is it just the occasional component now and then? Being exposed to flux fumes over time isn't healthy, it can cause allergies and respiratory problems. You don't need to worry about physical particles much, but always clean your hands after soldering. It is sensible to treat the soldering process for what it is - an industrial process. Perfectly safe if done proper, but not something you should be doing in your bedroom or kitchen.
